# AD790JNZ constant high output

Tags: comparator

I am using a AD790JNZ comparator and am always getting a high output regardless of the input. It is connected as in the image below and is powered by a single 5V - 0V. When +In is greater than -IN the output is high but also when +IN is less than -IN the output is still high when it should be low. Is there something missing here?

[image]

Comment: "Is there something missing here?" For one, you're missing the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD790.pdf). You should provide the datasheet in your question instead of making us look it up. The datasheet says that "When not in use, Pin 5 should be connected to the positive logic supply." So try connecting LATCH to VLOGIC.

Comment: Indeed it does. I need more sleep. I have put a 1k resistor between pin5 and supply and it works ok now. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I posted that as an answer since that was the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD790.pdf) says that

> When not in use, Pin 5 should be connected to the positive logic supply.

**You need to connect LATCH (pin 5) to the VLOGIC pin.** If LATCH is floating or low then

> the output remains in the high or low state, and does not respond to changing inputs.